# Any way to detect start of update-draw , end of update-draw for QGraphicsFrameWork?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'd need to know this two points. 
When starts an update-drawing and when ends.

In addittion I'need a way to interrupt this, in example when you are making zoom.
Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`QWidget::update` requests the widget (or a portion thereof) to be repainted. Several `update` requests may be merged into a single paint request.

Thus, it might be helpful to re-implement the virtual `paintEvent` method. Something like:

```
void MyGraphicsView::paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event) {
  // Do stuff before repainting

  // Do the actual paint update
  QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);

  // Do stuff after painting
}
```

If that's not what you were asking, please clarify your question; I wasn't totally sure I understood it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I use the Qg to draw QGraphicItems (points, polygons, etc ). It is a typical behavior that when you are going to zooming or panning you makes some events in quick succession. In example you rotate the mouse wheel 3 times and when I have a lot of graphical data, the first two wheel events are useless. What I need is a way to stop current update process if it is present. Thanks